# Java exception java.sql.SQLException: HikariDataSource HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1) has been closed

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, hikaricp

I have a springboot application which when I try to run I get the following exception

```
2020-08-05 12:27:44.061  WARN 11720 --- [nfoReplicator-0] o.s.b.a.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator   : DataSource health check failed

org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: HikariDataSource HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1) has been closed.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.getProduct(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doDataSourceHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1625)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaHealthCheckHandler.getStatus(EurekaHealthCheckHandler.java:195)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaHealthCheckHandler.getHealthStatus(EurekaHealthCheckHandler.java:176)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaHealthCheckHandler.getStatus(EurekaHealthCheckHandler.java:170)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshInstanceInfo(DiscoveryClient.java:1419)
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: HikariDataSource HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1) has been closed.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:96)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

My application-dev.yml file

```
  datasource:
datasource1:
  type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apitesting?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
  username: root
  password: root
  hikari:
    idle-timeout: 3000
    poolName: Hikari
    auto-commit: false
    data-source-properties:
      cachePrepStmts: true
      prepStmtCacheSize: 250
      prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
      useServerPrepStmts: true

  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    database: MYSQL
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
      hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: false
      hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
      hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
      hibernate.generate_statistics: false
      hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
```

When I run the application it connects to the db (MySql) creates all the tables then the connection seems to close. The same code works when i clone it from git and run it another system.

Comment: Is this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Check the port number on which your MySQL is running. It solved my problem once